# In pm2 log format "YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm Z" what does "Z" mean?

Tags: pm2

In the example https://github.com/Unitech/PM2/blob/master/ADVANCED_README.md to start pm2 is shown as

```
pm2 start app.js --log-date-format "YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm Z"
```

what does "Z" mean ?. In the logs it prints **+04:00**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Z means "display the time zone". So it will be displaying your local time, and also display that you are 4 hours ahead of UTC (which is Greenwich Mean Time without Daylight Saving Time, or GMT without DST).

If we started this app at the exact same time, with me being near London, may computer would display a time four hours away from yours, and +00:00. Just like my watch would display a different time than yours.